# react-native-ble-manager, not getting any indications in connected device

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Am using this library for connecting and communicating with a Bluetooth device such as bulb, headset.
Am able to connect to a headset and play audio on certain event like a specific socket event. Till this all is good.
But when I try to connect to a smartwatch over Bluetooth am able to initiate a connection and retrieve the services.

From the services some have property like Notify, Indicate, Read, Write

When using the service which supports Write and try to write a data there is no indication on Smart Watch regarding it.

also how can we initiate a indication(vibration/ring) in connected smart watch from our mobile app.

Am I doing something wrong. Can anyone guide me on this please.

// code

```
const handleWriteData = () => {

    BleManager.write(smartWatchId.id, 'fee7', 'fec7', data)
      .then(() => {
        // Success code
        console.log('Writed: ' + data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Failure code
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

EDIT 1

Any indication like ring or vibrate on when we use Write method from ReactNative. Also when I call the retrieve Services, getting a list of peripheral characteristics but unable to identify the purpose of each characteristics.

Is there any link or doc available to indicate the purpose of characteristics

Comment: Do let us know if u figure out this at any time

Comment: What do you expect to happen on the Smartwatch when writing a characteristic?

Comment: any indication like ring or vibrate on successfull write from smart watch side ?
also when i call the retrieve Services, getting a list of peripheral characteristics but unable to identify the purpose of each characteristics.

Comment: @VishalM What kind of smartwatch are you using? I've never seen a smartwatch that offers information on its services, they are usually encrypted to prevent users without the manufacturer's app. Also if the smartwatch is not programmed to show any indication of a succesfull writing operation it will never do so

Comment: @VishalM regarding the purpose of characteristics: There is the [Assigned Numbers Document](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/assigned-numbers/) which includes all 16-Bit UUIDs that the Bluetooth SIG has assigned to companies. But devices often use custom UUIDs and also custom protocols with no way to tell what the characteristic does.

Comment: smartwatch - firebolt BSWO43
https://phonewaleonline.com/product/fire-boltt-ring-3-smart-watchwith-bluetooth-calling-118-sports-modes-rose-gold/

when i call retrieve Services getting a Json  -- 
 [{"characteristic": "2a00", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1800"}, {"characteristic": "2a01", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1800"}, {"characteristic": "2aa6", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1800"}, {"characteristic": "2ac9", "properties": {"Read": "Read"}, "service": "1800"},...] actually getting around 40+ objects in this array.

Comment: Please take a look at the assigned numbers document I linked above, you will find some of the UUIDs there